# LD_PRELOAD shared library with malloc/free on ls

Tags: c, malloc, shared-libraries

I trying to detect memory leaks in my program. In order to get the idea, I tried `malloc()` and `free()` on `ls` by `LD_PRELOAD`'ing the shared library.

```
void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    char buf[60];
    static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;

    if (real_malloc == NULL) {
        *(void**)(&real_malloc) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    }

    void* mem = real_malloc(size);
    sprintf(buf, "malloc called, size = %5zu, ptr=%p\n", size, mem);
    write(2, buf, strlen(buf));
    return mem;
}
```

and running with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libmcount.so ls
```

I got the following output:

```
malloc called, size =   472, ptr=0x556d7a7682d0
malloc called, size =   120, ptr=0x556d7a7684b0
malloc called, size =  1024, ptr=0x556d7a768530
free called, ptr address = 0x556d7a7684b0
free called, ptr address = 0x556d7a768530
free called, ptr address = 0x556d7a7682d0
free called, ptr address = (nil)
malloc called, size =     5, ptr=0x556d7a768940
free called, ptr address = 0x556d7a768940
malloc called, size =   120, ptr=0x556d7a7684b0
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a768940
malloc called, size =   776, ptr=0x556d7a768960
malloc called, size =   112, ptr=0x556d7a768c70
malloc called, size =  1336, ptr=0x556d7a768cf0
malloc called, size =   216, ptr=0x556d7a769230
malloc called, size =   432, ptr=0x556d7a769310
malloc called, size =   104, ptr=0x556d7a7694d0
malloc called, size =    88, ptr=0x556d7a769540
malloc called, size =   120, ptr=0x556d7a7695a0
malloc called, size =   168, ptr=0x556d7a769620
malloc called, size =   104, ptr=0x556d7a7696d0
malloc called, size =    80, ptr=0x556d7a769740
malloc called, size =   192, ptr=0x556d7a7697a0
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a769870
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a769890
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a7698b0
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a7698d0
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a7698f0
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a769910
malloc called, size =     5, ptr=0x556d7a769930
free called, ptr address = 0x556d7a769930
malloc called, size =   120, ptr=0x556d7a769950
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a769930
malloc called, size =   776, ptr=0x556d7a7699d0
malloc called, size =   112, ptr=0x556d7a769ce0
malloc called, size =  1336, ptr=0x556d7a769d60
malloc called, size =   216, ptr=0x556d7a76a2a0
malloc called, size =   432, ptr=0x556d7a76a380
malloc called, size =   104, ptr=0x556d7a76a540
malloc called, size =    88, ptr=0x556d7a76a5b0
malloc called, size =   120, ptr=0x556d7a76a610
malloc called, size =   168, ptr=0x556d7a76a690
malloc called, size =   104, ptr=0x556d7a76a740
malloc called, size =    80, ptr=0x556d7a76a7b0
malloc called, size =   192, ptr=0x556d7a76a810
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a76a8e0
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a76a900
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a76a920
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a76a940
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a76a960
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a76a980
malloc called, size =   281, ptr=0x556d7a76a9a0
free called, ptr address = (nil)
free called, ptr address = (nil)
malloc called, size =    34, ptr=0x556d7a76aad0
malloc called, size =    10, ptr=0x556d7a76ab00
malloc called, size =    56, ptr=0x556d7a76ab20
malloc called, size =    56, ptr=0x556d7a76ab60
malloc called, size =   128, ptr=0x556d7a76aba0
malloc called, size = 20000, ptr=0x556d7a76ac30
malloc called, size =    32, ptr=0x556d7a76fa60
malloc called, size =     2, ptr=0x556d7a76fa90
malloc called, size = 32816, ptr=0x556d7a76fab0
malloc called, size =    11, ptr=0x556d7a777af0
malloc called, size =    13, ptr=0x556d7a777b10
malloc called, size =    15, ptr=0x556d7a777b30
malloc called, size =    14, ptr=0x556d7a777b50
malloc called, size =    18, ptr=0x556d7a777b70
malloc called, size =     7, ptr=0x556d7a777b90
malloc called, size =     5, ptr=0x556d7a777bb0
malloc called, size =    12, ptr=0x556d7a777bd0
free called, ptr address = 0x556d7a76fab0
free called, ptr address = (nil)
malloc called, size =   192, ptr=0x556d7a76fab0
malloc called, size =  1088, ptr=0x556d7a76fd10
malloc called, size =  1024, ptr=0x556d7a768530
1-build.sh  libmcount.so
2-run.sh  malloc.c
free called, ptr address = 0x556d7a76fa90
free called, ptr address = (nil)
free called, ptr address = 0x556d7a76fa60
free called, ptr address = 0x556d7a768530
```

What puzzles me is that there are much more malloc than free calls in the output, even though I omitted `realloc`/`calloc`/`memalign` functions. I thought they should pair up. Valgrind reports no leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Valgrind will not show "reachable" memory blocks i.e. blocks which are still accessible by the program through global pointers or stack variables. This can be altered with `--show-reachable=yes`.

As for unfreed memory, it's normally faster to just terminate the program than bother freeing all the allocated blocks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Interestingly I got 52 frees from valgrind and from my shared library just 14. Can you explain the discrepancy?
`==19700== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19700==     in use at exit: 22,358 bytes in 16 blocks
==19700==   total heap usage: 68 allocs, 52 frees, 66,047 bytes allocated`

Comment: No, it's actually quite puzzling. My only guess is that `realloc` calls `free` internally through a private alias so it's not intercepted by your hooks.